# R: Plotting Confidence Bands Issue

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot confidence bands for a regression, using a function but the lines for my upper and lower prediction bands look weird and blurry. Can anyone spot the issue, because I can't seem to find anything wrong?

Here is the code:

```
drawPrediction <- function(x, y) {

  lm.model <- lm(y ~ x)
  ci <- predict(lm.model, interval = "prediction")
  plot(x,y)
  abline(lm.model, col = "red")
  lines(x, ci[,2], lty = 2, col = 'blue')
  lines(x,ci[,3], lty = 2, col = 'blue' )

}
```

Gives this result for some test data (the R state.x77 data, regressing Income on Illiteracy):

[image]

This is the code I used for the test above:

```
> test <- as.data.frame(state.x77)
> drawPrediction(test$Illiteracy, test$Income)
```

Comment: Hi, sorry about that I added the source of the test data. I think that along with the code should be enough to reproduce?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the x's are not sorted so you are drawing lines all over the place, not just between consecutive x's.  Instead, use

```
lm.model <- lm(Income ~ Illiteracy, data=as.data.frame(state.x77))
  ci <- predict(lm.model, interval = "prediction")
  plot(x,y)
  abline(lm.model, col = "red")
  lines(sort(x), ci[order(x),2], lty = 2, col = 'blue')
  lines(sort(x), ci[order(x),3], lty = 2, col = 'blue' )
```

[image: Sorted x's]

Comment: Yes! Thank you I was just starting to realize this was an issue. Thank you so much!